# Adding libraries to app from JBoss 7.1.1 modules

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I'm using Intellij Idea 12 and the JBoss 7.1.1 app server. Do I need to add the javaee6 jar to my application library in order to deploy it?

Or, can I just add the libraries that contain implementations of Java EE technologies, such as Faces, EJB, the Java EE jar file itself and so on from the modules in JBoss AS 7.1.1?

What if, for example, I want to add JSF libraries to my app library from the modules in JBoss 7.1.1? How can I do that?

And what is situation with Maven? How are the dependencies resolved in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss is a Java EE 6 compliant application server, meaning that it has all the implementations of the Java EE standard on board already, These libraries are avaliabel to applications at runtime, so there is no need to add any additional libraries to use all Java EE 6 features.

If you are using maven, simply reference the libraries to be used at runtime ('provided' scope) like this

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are not sure where to start, try one or several projects from the [JBoss quickstarts](https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart). There is at least one for each major Java EE technology and some examples that put those technologies together.

EDIT: It seems that the real question here is how to add Java EE libs to your poroject, It depends on the build system. If you are using maven, and I would advise you to, pick a quickstart from the list - the [kitchesink](https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart/tree/master/kitchensink) is a good example and take a look at the `pom.xml`. It is not a good idea to add an implementation of a Java EE standard to your project other than the ones provided by the application server. This might cause problems on deployment or at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kostja. But when I am writing code (which has connection with JSF for example) in Idea the code can not compile (it is highlighted with red color) So Do I need to add jsf library to my app library? What if That library is different from the  libary in JBOSS 7

Comment: @ArtyMathJava - you still need to tell the IDE where to look for the libs. I have added some details to the answer